# asp.net mvc who is online

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Greetings, 
can someone give me some advices or links that will help me to implement to following scenario.
Page will be written in asp.net mvc. Authorization is going to be implemented by Memberships. The scenario is as follows:

> User1 has just logged in. After a
>   while, User2 attempts to login with
>   success. Then user1 should be notified
>   that User2 has just logged in. Additionally User2
>   should be notified that User1 is
>   online.

How can I achieve something like that? It should also be possible for these users to write messages to each other. (chat like).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are methods to do this in the asp.net membership providers, specifically, IsUserOnline() and something like CountUsersOnline(). The only problem with these methods is that they are really lame. They depend on the membership provider's LastActivityDate() and a window you can set in web.config. In other words, the user is considered online if his last encounter with the membership provider plus the time window in web.config has not expired.

We took this scenairo and made it work for us by setting up a Comet server, and pinging the Web server every ten minutes. When the Web server is pinged, it updates the LastActivityDate of the membership provider.

We set the activity window to 12 minutes, as well as the Session timer. This allows us to determine who is online to an accuracy of aproximately ten minutes.

---

Here is the line in Web.config:

```
    <membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="12">
```

---

Here is jQuery Comet server:

```
  function getData() { 
    $.getJSON("/Account/Timer", gotData); 
  } 

  // Whenever a query stops, start a new one.    
  $(document).ajaxStop(getData, 600000);

  // Start the first query.
  getData();
```

---

Here's our server code:

```
    public JsonResult Timer()
    {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Name);
            user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;

            Membership.UpdateUser(user);

            // You can return anything to reset the timer.
            return Json(new { Timer = "reset" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you need some jQuery polling to happen.

You can easily do a jQuery post to an ActionResult which would then check for users online and returns a PartialView back to the calling jQuery function.

The returning PartialView might have all the users logged in which can then be popped up in some sort of animating panel.

Use javascript to execute a timed poll back to the controller.

Comment: yes, i was thinking about the similar solution but how should I check who is online? How to create a functionality (from the server side of view)

Comment: Think when a user logs in you'll need to write a db entry and on session end of that user, delete the entry perhaps.

You could, i guess, keep all the logged in users in a cache and remove them on session end.  either way i think you need to log them somewhere and utilise session end or something

Comment: ok, and any suggesstions how can I do this: "You could, i guess, keep all the logged in users in a cache and remove them on session end" in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get onlines *live* in web. you should refresh page or refresh content with ajax -or else-. So it gonna solve i think.

ps. chat and online issues, you have two options; you can store them in database -*its what i suggest*- or store in memory, you may want to look [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/AliAspNetChat.aspx)

Tables:

```
Users
-Id / int - identity
-LoginTime / datetime
-IsOnline / bit

Friends
-Id / int - identity
-FirstUserId / int
-SecondUserId / int

public class UserInformation
{
    public IList<User> OnlineFriends { get; set;}
    public IList<User> JustLoggedFriends { get; set; } /* For notifications */
}

public class UserRepository
{
    public UserInformation GetInformation(int id, DateTime lastCheck)
    {
        return Session.Linq<User>()
                .Where(u => u.Id == id)
                .Select(u => new { 
                              User = u,
                              Friends = u.Friends.Where(f => f.FirstUser.Id == u.Id || f.SecondUser.Id == u.Id)
                })
                .Select(a => new UserInformation {
                                JustLoggedFriends = u.Friends.Where(f => f.IsOnline && f.OnlineTime >= lastCheck).ToList(), 
                                OnlineFriends = u.Friends.Where(f => f.IsOnline).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();
    }
}

public class UserService
{
    public UserInformation GetInformation(int id, DateTime lastCheck)
    {
        return repository.GetInformation(id, lastCheck);
    }
}
```

UI:

```
public class UserController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = (int)Session["UserId"];
        var lastCheck = (DateTime)Session["LastCheck"];
        UserInformation info = userService.GetInformation(userId, lastCheck);
        Session["LastCheck"] = DateTime.Now;

        //show up notifications and online users.
    }
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        User user = null; // TODO: get user by username and password
        Session["UserId"] = user.Id;
        Session["LastCheck"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to implement it so it can check (by using GetUserOnlineFriends) periodically - let's say every two minutes -user's friends?. Additionally how to implement possibility to chat between these two friends?

Comment: not limited. you may check session_start and session_end event then update user online -column- when session_start's fired and when end's fired update users record as offline - column _data type of bit_ gonna solve this. and then if users online show up them. but this algorithm's not for you, session gonna solve that. i understood its now. editing now.